# How to select everything that is NOT part of this string in database field?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

First: I'm using Access 2010.

What I need to do is pull everything in a field out that is NOT a certain string. Say for example you have this:

00123457**A8V**

Those last 3 characters that are bolded are just an example; that portion can be any combination of numbers/letters and from 2-4 characters long. The 00123457 portion will always be the same. So what I would need to have returned by my query in the example above is the "A8V".

I have a vague idea of how to do this, which involved using the Right function, with (field length - the last position in that string). So what I had was

```
SELECT Right(Facility.ID, (Len([ID) - InstrRev([ID], "00123457")))
FROM Facility;
```

Logically in this mind it would work, however Access 2010 complains that I am using the Right function incorrectly. Can someone here help me figure this out?

Many thanks!

Comment: use LTRIM to trim off from the left

Comment: Can you provide some more examples of example strings and what you want to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a replace function?

```
REPLACE(Facility.ID, "00123457", "")
```

Comment: This worked perfect for me... can't believe I didn't think of something this simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing square bracket in here `Len([ID)`

You also need to reverse this "00123457" in `InStrRev()`, but you don't need `InStrRev()`, just `InStr()`.

Comment: Your requirement is unclear though. You need to clarify with sample data, and a description of what would be returned from these samples.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the last three characters of the string.

The simple syntax: Right([string],3) will yield the results you desire.

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx)

For example:

```
(TABLE1)
| ID  | STRING        |
------------------------
|  1  | 001234567A8V  |
|  2  | 008765432A8V  |
|  3  | 005671234A8V  |
```

So then you'd run this query:

```
SELECT Right([Table1.STRING],3) AS Result from Table1;
```

And the Query returns:

```
(QUERY)
|   RESULT    |
---------------
| A8V         |
| A8V         |
| A8V         |
```

EDIT:

After seeing the need for the end string to be 2-4 characters while the original, left portion of the string is 00123457 (8 characters), try this:

```
SELECT Right([Table1].[string],(Len([Table1].[string])-'8')) AS Result
FROM table1;
```

Comment: JBC I tried your query but all it returned was #func! for the results... any idea why that is? I went through and changed the query to fit my database.

Comment: Do you have a sample table data you could toss up. I'll take a look. I'm not familiar with "#func!" errors, unless you missed syntax. Syntax in ACCESS is extremely important.